# can hightcharts make ajax calls to external data files?

Tags: highcharts

I am converting R data frames to json format and write these to files. I like to use hightcharts to chart these json formated files. Is there a was to call external json files to build charts with hightcharts without any server side programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write javascript to load a Highcharts series from an external json format file.  In fact, that's what many of the samples do, [including this one](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping).  If you look at the javascript code in "View options", you'll see it's loading the series from an URL:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?...', function(data) {
    // create the chart using the data loaded from the above URL
});
```

Comment: Joe, I dont have php. I have IIS and bunch of rson files. Maybe call the rson files within iis files.

Comment: Doesn't have to be PHP - that URL could be pointing to a static json-formatted file.

Comment: I am really sorry I am very new to this think. My index.html and data.json file are on the same folder. can you help me start with this?

Comment: Have you tried $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { ... }, i.e. using a relative path to your json file.

Comment: yes. my data.sjon file looks like this: {"DATETIME":[1369540800,1369541700,1369542600,1369543500],"CPU":[14.84,13.6333333333333,14.7666666666667,13.5333333333333]}

Comment: Looks like you have two arrays: DATETIME with the X values and CPU for the Y values.  You need to provide data in one of the formats used by HighCharts: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Comment: You need to have series object like pairs: {"data":[[1369540800,14.84],[1369540800,14.84]...} In other cases you should prepare parser which transform your json to correct figure. I advice to familiar with http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I changed my data.sjon to this, still no data data points: {"data":[[1369540800,14.84],[1369540800,14.84]]}

Comment: Do you receive any errors? In getJSON could you use console.log(data) and display what you receive?